# Scenarios for objects moving 99.99% the speed of light. How long will it take them?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

**My understanding:**

It's my understanding that when travelling close to the speed of light, that time dilation occurs.

I've seen different formulae

I found this formula:

$\Delta t' =  \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

From this website: https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/time-dilation

Using the calculator on that site, it tells me that if you travel at 0.9999c for 1 year, then from the perspective of the traveller, 5.17 days will have passed. (Based on the reference frame of where you're travelling to/from, and their speed relative to each other).

**Scenario**

So, say we simplified the universe down to two star systems (A and B) 1 light year apart, and not moving relative to each other. There's nothing else in this universe, no other frames of reference to point to.

**Experiment 1**

A traveller (Bob) decides to travel from A to B at 0.9999c, acceleration is instant. He leaves 2023-01-01, and as it's 1LY apart, he arrives 2024-01-01, but when he checks his ship's calendar, the date is 2023-01-06.

This experiment I feel is pretty straight forward.

**Experiment 2**

Everyone has synced up their calendars, the date is 2024-01-01.

Scientists attach massive thrusters to A and B. A accelerates instantly to 0.9999c (relative to Bob) away from B, and B accelerates instantly to 0.9999c (relative to Bob) towards A. Effectively they do not move at all relative to each other, but expend a lot of energy doing so.

Bob was sitting in space next to B, and does nothing. So for him, B flies away from him, and A flies towards him.

Things are now reversed, According to Bob's calendar, A arrives to Bob on 2025-01-01, and A is 1LY away on the same date. However, According to A and B's calendar, the date is 2025-01-06.

And to anyone who didn't know about the thrusters (and didn't feel their effects), to them, it just looks like Bob went around his ship doing a year's worth of things in the space of 5.17 days.

**Experiment 3**

Let's combine our first two experiments. Everyone's synced up their calendars, the date is 2025-01-01. Bob is sitting in his ship near A.

All at once, A travels at 0.9999c (relative to Bob) away from B, B travels 0.9999c (relative to Bob) towards A.

Now Bob, drops a beacon, creating a new frame of reference. Then flies off towards B at 0.9999c (relative to the beacon).

After six months (according to the beacon), Bob and B meet in the middle, all parties promptly come to a halt relative to the beacon (which promptly destroys itself).

Now, here's my expectation: Everyone's calendars show 2025-01-03. Bob was at A, and is now at B, and only 2.58 days have passed for everyone.

While it took energy input from all three parties, the effective result is that Bob has travelled roughly 142x the speed of light. At least as far as you could infer if all you had to look at was calendars/clocks.

**Question**

I know the energy requirements for all these are impractical, if not impossible.

But still, is my understanding and assessment of each of these experiments correct?

Comment: If you are going to put dates in then use a system like "2025 Jan 03" because "2025 01 03" is ambigous and people in different countries may interpret that differently.  It could be read as Jan 3rd or Mar 1st.

Comment: Of the exceptionally few countries that "officially" use some format of YDM, none use "yyyy-mm-dd", so I'm not sure this leaves room for ambiguity. ISO 8601 is pretty clear.

Comment: @ElDubs, you are assuming that everyone is familiar with ISO 8601.  Until I read your reply, I had never heard of it, and I definitely don't know what it says.  StephenG has a good point, and it wouldn't take much effort on your part to edit your post.

Comment: Does this "calculator" handle leap-years, if it went beyond February in a leap year? It's best that all answers be given in (say) days. (Calendar math is an unnecessary complication.)

Comment: @DavidWhite Note I also left clarification in my original comment by stating "5.17 days will have passed". I don't mind adding further clarification, but would you say that would be enough? That said, yeah, there was no reason to add calendar math, that's true.

Comment: @ElDubs, 5.17 days is more than enough information to clarify what you are saying.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of slips in your reasoning which lead you to a false conclusion.

The first slip is in Experiment 2. You have said that the thrusters are synchronised so that A and B always remain one light year apart in their common rest frame. In that case, the set-up is essentially the same as Experiment 1, and will give the same answer- so only six days will pass for Bob between B departing and A arriving, and not the year you supposed. The reason is that distance is frame dependent, so if A and B are always a light year apart in a common rest frame, then they will always be length contracted to about six light days apart in Bob's frame.

Your second slip is in Experiment 3 where you assume A and B are a light year apart in the frame of the beacon. Again, that's a mistake if A and B are a light year apart in their common rest frame, as they will only be just under six light days apart in the frame of the beacon.

Two more general points you might find helpful, as follows...

Firstly, I recommend you study the relativity of simultaneity until you really grasps its implications, as it is the underlying cause in SR of both time dilation and length contraction.

Secondly, one consequence of the relativity of simultaneity is that you have to be really careful to consider simultaneity when you think about two bodies some distance apart accelerating relative to a third body. The question is whether they are accelerating simultaneously with respect to each other or with respect to the third body, as they are two quite separate scenarios with quite different consequences.

Comment: For experiment 2: You're saying that A and B both moving laterally, means it effectively becomes equivalent to Experiment 1? And time therefore dilates for Bob, rather than the two stars, even though they are the ones providing thrust.

What if only A moved, then it would arrive at Bob and B after 5.17 days for itself, but one year will have passed for Bob and B. If then B did its movement afterwards, it would arrive 1LY away after 5.17 days for itself, but Bob and A will have seen it take 1 year.

Why does both stars moving at once mean Bob no longer experiences years at a time, but days?

Comment: No, you are imagining things incorrectly. I'm afraid it is impossible to explain special relativity from scratch in comments like this. You'll need to study it. It is very easy to misunderstand, especially if you try to apply common sense thinking to it, as relativity doesn't agree with the common sense intuitions we develop.

Comment: But I will just give you a tip- all the effects of SR are symmetric, and all speeds are relative. Relative to you, a muon might be passing at close to the speed of light and might be time dilated by  a factor of sixty- but you are moving at close to the speed of light relative to that muon, and to that muon it is you who is time dilated by a factor of sixty, so your heart beats about once a minute in the muon's frame.

Answer (score -1):

**Mistakes:**

1: Accelerated frames are messy. Accelerating your observers and then pretending the acceleration is instant and can therefore be ignored is a mistake. A person "accelerated instantly" measures 0/0 time pass, which is undefined, so you've blown up your thought experiment at the start. Neither is accelerating them "near-instantaneously" to avoid the undefined result an easy way out. You've just turned an otherwise easy special relativity problem into a hard general relativity problem. I'll come back to this in the very end.

If you are doing a special relativity thought experiment, you keep things special-relativity and avoid thorny general relativity problems: keep all observers at the same velocity through the whole experiment wherever possible. If you can't keep them the same velocity, don't track their clocks  at all across the times when they're accelerating, and don't have them take any measurements while accelerating - essentially just use a series of different inertial observers that happen to have the same names.

2: Not only times but distances are observer-dependent. Take the first scenario:
A and B are comoving. Bob travels at .9999c past A in the direction of B. He therefore measures B approaching him at .9999c. He measures that it will take B 5.17 days to reach him. Bob therefore measures that the distance from A to B is 5.17 light-days. This distance between A and B doesn't change unless Bob's velocity changes.

3: Observers should generally define their own coordinate systems with themselves stationary at the origin. This is not strictly necessary, but it makes both math and intuition much easier.

**Experiment walkthroughs:**

Experiments 1 and 2 are identical once we adopt the convention of treating our observer frame as stationary, whichever observer we pick.

In Bob's frame, Bob is stationary in his space ship. A has just zipped past him and is receding at .9999c. B is approaching at .9999c. Bob does a quick calculation and concludes that since 5.17 days will pass between now and when B reaches him, B's time dilation factor is about 1:70.6, that is, a bit under 2 hours will have passed in B's frame from whatever time it is now. But B traveling towards Bob at 0.9999c, so of course light from B emitted right now will reach Bob barely any faster than B itself - a bit under two hours faster, to be precise. In the mean time, Bob does some simple arithmetic: 0.9999c minus c is 0.0001c. The distance between Bob and B is 5.17 light-days, so light reaching Bob from B right now has gotten 5.17 light days ahead of B at a relative velocity of 0.0001c. Divide distance by velocity for time: the light was emitted from B 51700 days (about 142 years) ago and 51700 light days away - but B has a time dilation factor of about 70.6, so the light Bob is seeing from B was emitted about 2 years ago in B's frame.
Bob looks at a B calendar through his x-ray telescope and sees B's date is 0.00 years. Meanwhile, passing A, Bob sees that A's date is 1.00 years.

5.17 days days later, having flown through two years worth of B's light, Bob glances out of his window with his X-ray telescope just before B passes him. Unsurprisingly, he sees that the calendar says the date is 2.00 years, even though Bob knows full well that only two hours have passed in B's frame since he passed A. After all, he knew that the light he saw that said the date was 0.00 years was two years old a few days ago.

Meanwhile in A's frame, Alice is watching things unfold through her telescope. She sees Bob zip past at 0.9999c. She looks through her telescope and sees that it is year 0.00 on planet B, 1 light year away. She smiles to herself, knowing that it is year 1.00 on planet A, so 1 light year away, it must be year 1.00 on B, too. She sends Bob a signal informing him of this, but she knows that, since he's zipping away at 0.9999c, he won't receive her message for two years even though he's only just now passed her.

She measures Bob's time dilation factor to be 1:70.5, so she knows that he will observe 5.17 days pass as he travels from A to B, and in that time he will watch two years of B's history zoom past him because he's flying through two years worth of light emitted by B at almost the speed of light.

As planet B is celebrating their own year 1.00 (which, according to their clock synchronization convention, is the same time that Alice is looking through her telescope), Beth looks through her telescope. She sees planet A's calendars reading 0.00 through her telescope. She sees Bob 0.9999 light years farther away than A, but she knows that he is traveling towards B past A at .9999c so she calculates trivially that Bob must right now be passing A, while A is celebrating year 1.00.
So Bob is speeding towards the light being emitted from B right now, through light emitted a year ago. By the time he arrives a little over a year from now in year 2.00, he will have flown through 2 years of B's light. When will he see the light from what Beth is doing right now at year 1.00? The light and Bob have a closing velocity, in Beth's frame, of 1.9999c, and a distance of 1 LY, so Bob will see Beth and year 1.00 through his telescope when Bob and the light meet in 1/(1.9999) years, when Bob has traveled 0.9999/1.9999 of the distance. Hold on to this number, we'll need it later.

---

In experiment 3, we have relativistic velocity composition. Let's reframe it this way:
Reset the experiment to the time (according to the planets' clock synchronization) when both planets measure year 1.00, but this time start Bob near planet B traveling towards planet A, and give Alice a space ship too.
Alice passes A traveling towards B and Bob passes B traveling towards A, both traveling at 0.9999c. In 6 months (in the frame of A or B) they pass in the middle and read each other's clocks.
Take Bob's frame, that is, Bob is stationary, B is receeding, A is approaching, Alice is (eventually) approaching faster than A.
Bob measures Alice pass A through his x-ray telescope. At the moment she passes A, he sees an A-orbiting space cop with "year 1.00" on his calendar catch her on his radar gun going 0.9999c over the speed limit. Bob does [relativistic velocity composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) and calculates Alice's velocity relative to himself is 0.999999995c, so her time dilation factor is 0.0001.

Bob once again measured the starting distance from A to B as 5.17 light days, and the starting calendar date on A as year 0.00, light from which was emitted 51700 days ago and 51700 light-days away in Bob's frame. But Alice passed A when Bob saw A's date was 1.00, at which time A had traveled 0.9999/1.9999 of the distance to Bob since the light was emitted from year 0.00, so the distance was 25848.7 light days, and the light was emitted 25848.7 days ago. Bob does simple arithmetic, converts to a more useful unit, and concludes that Alice is 11 light-seconds away right now, having been traveling at just under the speed of light for 25848.7 days. Sure enough, over the next 11 seconds, Bob sees Alice get bigger and brighter and eventually flash past him at 0.999999995c.
Of course, Bob knows Alice's time dilation factor is 0.0001, so Bob is completely unsurprised to see that her clock displays that 2.58 days have passed since she passed A, which is the same as the reading on Bob's clock since Bob passed B (which is now 2.58 light years in the distance behind him). But Bob knows that *really*, Alice has been traveling for about 70 years.

Bob's frame and Alice's frame are perfect mirror images, so Alice measures the exact same facts about Bob and B that Bob measured about Alice and A.

So: Alice, Bob, A, and B, disagree wildly on the geometry of spacetime, but they all agree on what events happened in what order for which frame, and what everyone's clock should read, and what everyone should measure at all times.

---

Going back for a second to accelerated frames. If we start Bob stationary with respect to A, for example, Bob measures that year 1.00 on A is *right now* - he sees light from year 0.00 emanating from 1 light year away. If he boosts into a frame where A is moving towards him at 0.9999c, he then measures that year 1.00 on A was 70 years in his past. *Where did Bob get 70 years?* I have no idea how to do the math, but I know that if we gave Bob the ability to boost from 0 to 0.9999c relative to his initial velocity without experiencing significant accelerated-frame effects, *we've given Bob a time machine*, and any thought experiment that starts with "Suppose Bob has a time machine" can only avoid nonsense results by sheer dumb luck.